# Trying to call a jquery function from inside a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, closures, impromptu

Ok, So I am trying to use this 3rd party js library, called jquery-impromptu.js, the js code looks like this:

```
/*! jQuery-Impromptu - v5.2.4 - 2014-05-26
* http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu
* Copyright (c) 2014 Trent Richardson; Licensed MIT */
(function($) {

"use strict";

/**
* setDefaults - Sets the default options
* @param message String/Object - String of html or Object of states
* @param options Object - Options to set the prompt
* @return jQuery - container with overlay and prompt 
*/
$.prompt = function(message, options) {
    // only for backwards compat, to be removed in future version
    if(options !== undefined && options.classes !== undefined && typeof options.classes === 'string'){
        options = { box: options.classes };
    }

    $.prompt.options = $.extend({},$.prompt.defaults,options);
    $.prompt.currentPrefix = $.prompt.options.prefix;

    // Be sure any previous timeouts are destroyed
    if($.prompt.timeout){
        clearTimeout($.prompt.timeout);
    }
    $.prompt.timeout = false;

    var opts = $.prompt.options,
        $body = $(document.body),
        $window = $(window);

    //build the box and fade
    var msgbox = '<div class="'+ $.prompt.options.prefix +'box '+ opts.classes.box +'">';
    if(opts.useiframe && ($('object, applet').length > 0)) {
        msgbox += '<iframe src="javascript:false;" style="display:block;position:absolute;z-index:-1;" class="'+ opts.prefix +'fade '+ opts.classes.fade +'"></iframe>';
    } else {
        msgbox +='<div class="'+ opts.prefix +'fade '+ opts.classes.fade +'"></div>';
    }
    msgbox += '<div class="'+ opts.prefix +' '+ opts.classes.prompt +'">'+
                '<form action="javascript:false;" onsubmit="return false;" class="'+ opts.prefix +'form '+ opts.classes.form +'">'+
                    '<div class="'+ opts.prefix +'close '+ opts.classes.close +'">'+ opts.closeText +'</div>'+
                    '<div class="'+ opts.prefix +'states"></div>'+
                '</form>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>';

    $.prompt.jqib = $(msgbox).appendTo($body);
    $.prompt.jqi = $.prompt.jqib.children('.'+ opts.prefix);//.data('jqi',opts);
    $.prompt.jqif = $.prompt.jqib.children('.'+ opts.prefix +'fade');

    //if a string was passed, convert to a single state
    if(message.constructor === String){
        message = {
            state0: {
                title: opts.title,
                html: message,
                buttons: opts.buttons,
                position: opts.position,
                focus: opts.focus,
                defaultButton: opts.defaultButton,
                submit: opts.submit
            }
        };
    }

    //build the states
    $.prompt.options.states = {};
    var k,v;
    for(k in message){
        v = $.extend({},$.prompt.defaults.state,{name:k},message[k]);
        $.prompt.addState(v.name, v);

        if($.prompt.currentStateName === ''){
            $.prompt.currentStateName = v.name;
        }
    }

    //Events
    $.prompt.jqi.on('click', '.'+ opts.prefix +'buttons button', function(e){
        var $t = $(this),
            $state = $t.parents('.'+ opts.prefix +'state'),
            stateobj = $.prompt.options.states[$state.data('jqi-name')],
            msg = $state.children('.'+ opts.prefix +'message'),
            clicked = stateobj.buttons[$t.text()] || stateobj.buttons[$t.html()],
            forminputs = {};

        // if for some reason we couldn't get the value
        if(clicked === undefined){
            for(var i in stateobj.buttons){
                if(stateobj.buttons[i].title === $t.text() || stateobj.buttons[i].title === $t.html()){
                    clicked = stateobj.buttons[i].value;
                }
            }
        }

        //collect all form element values from all states.
        $.each($.prompt.jqi.children('form').serializeArray(),function(i,obj){
            if (forminputs[obj.name] === undefined) {
                forminputs[obj.name] = obj.value;
            } else if (typeof forminputs[obj.name] === Array || typeof forminputs[obj.name] === 'object') {
                forminputs[obj.name].push(obj.value);
            } else {
                forminputs[obj.name] = [forminputs[obj.name],obj.value];    
            } 
        });

        // trigger an event
        var promptsubmite = new $.Event('impromptu:submit');
        promptsubmite.stateName = stateobj.name;
        promptsubmite.state = $state;
        $state.trigger(promptsubmite, [clicked, msg, forminputs]);

        if(!promptsubmite.isDefaultPrevented()){
            $.prompt.close(true, clicked,msg,forminputs);
        }
    });

    // if the fade is clicked blink the prompt
    var fadeClicked = function(){
        if(opts.persistent){
            var offset = (opts.top.toString().indexOf('%') >= 0? ($window.height()*(parseInt(opts.top,10)/100)) : parseInt(opts.top,10)),
                top = parseInt($.prompt.jqi.css('top').replace('px',''),10) - offset;

            //$window.scrollTop(top);
            $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: top }, 'fast', function(){
                var i = 0;
                $.prompt.jqib.addClass(opts.prefix +'warning');
                var intervalid = setInterval(function(){
                    $.prompt.jqib.toggleClass(opts.prefix +'warning');
                    if(i++ > 1){
                        clearInterval(intervalid);
                        $.prompt.jqib.removeClass(opts.prefix +'warning');
                    }
                }, 100);
            });
        }
        else {
            $.prompt.close(true);
        }
    };

    // listen for esc or tab keys
    var keyDownEventHandler = function(e){
        var key = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;

        //escape key closes
        if(key === 27) {
            fadeClicked();  
        }

        //enter key pressed trigger the default button if its not on it, ignore if it is a textarea
        if(key === 13){
            var $defBtn = $.prompt.getCurrentState().find('.'+ opts.prefix +'defaultbutton');
            var $tgt = $(e.target);

            if($tgt.is('textarea,.'+opts.prefix+'button') === false && $defBtn.length > 0){
                e.preventDefault();
                $defBtn.click();
            }
        }

        //constrain tabs, tabs should iterate through the state and not leave
        if (key === 9){
            var $inputels = $('input,select,textarea,button',$.prompt.getCurrentState());
            var fwd = !e.shiftKey && e.target === $inputels[$inputels.length-1];
            var back = e.shiftKey && e.target === $inputels[0];
            if (fwd || back) {
                setTimeout(function(){ 
                    if (!$inputels){
                        return;
                    }
                    var el = $inputels[back===true ? $inputels.length-1 : 0];

                    if (el){
                        el.focus();
                    }
                },10);
                return false;
            }
        }
    };

    $.prompt.position();
    $.prompt.style();

    $.prompt.jqif.click(fadeClicked);
    $window.resize({animate:false}, $.prompt.position);
    $.prompt.jqi.find('.'+ opts.prefix +'close').click($.prompt.close);
    $.prompt.jqib.on("keydown",keyDownEventHandler)
                .on('impromptu:loaded', opts.loaded)
                .on('impromptu:close', opts.close)
                .on('impromptu:statechanging', opts.statechanging)
                .on('impromptu:statechanged', opts.statechanged);

    // Show it
    $.prompt.jqif[opts.show](opts.overlayspeed);
    $.prompt.jqi[opts.show](opts.promptspeed, function(){

        var $firstState = $.prompt.jqi.find('.'+ opts.prefix +'states .'+ opts.prefix +'state').eq(0);
        $.prompt.goToState($firstState.data('jqi-name'));

        $.prompt.jqib.trigger('impromptu:loaded');
    });

    // Timeout
    if(opts.timeout > 0){
        $.prompt.timeout = setTimeout(function(){ $.prompt.close(true); },opts.timeout);
    }

    return $.prompt.jqib;
};

$.prompt.defaults = {
    prefix:'jqi',
    classes: {
        box: '',
        fade: '',
        prompt: '',
        form: '',
        close: '',
        title: '',
        message: '',
        buttons: '',
        button: '',
        defaultButton: ''
    },
    title: '',
    closeText: '&times;',
    buttons: {
        Ok: true
    },
    loaded: function(e){},
    submit: function(e,v,m,f){},
    close: function(e,v,m,f){},
    statechanging: function(e, from, to){},
    statechanged: function(e, to){},
    opacity: 0.6,
    zIndex: 999,
    overlayspeed: 'slow',
    promptspeed: 'fast',
    show: 'fadeIn',
    focus: 0,
    defaultButton: 0,
    useiframe: false,
    top: '15%',
    position: { 
        container: null, 
        x: null, 
        y: null,
        arrow: null,
        width: null
    },
    persistent: true,
    timeout: 0,
    states: {},
    state: {
        name: null,
        title: '',
        html: '',
        buttons: {
            Ok: true
        },
        focus: 0,
        defaultButton: 0,
        position: { 
            container: null, 
            x: null, 
            y: null,
            arrow: null,
            width: null
        },
        submit: function(e,v,m,f){
            return true;
        }
    }
};

/**
* currentPrefix String - At any time this show be the prefix 
* of the current prompt ex: "jqi"
*/
$.prompt.currentPrefix = $.prompt.defaults.prefix;

/**
* currentStateName String - At any time this is the current state
* of the current prompt ex: "state0"
*/
$.prompt.currentStateName = "";

/**
* setDefaults - Sets the default options
* @param o Object - Options to set as defaults
* @return void
*/
$.prompt.setDefaults = function(o) {
    $.prompt.defaults = $.extend({}, $.prompt.defaults, o);
};

/**
* setStateDefaults - Sets the default options for a state
* @param o Object - Options to set as defaults
* @return void
*/
$.prompt.setStateDefaults = function(o) {
    $.prompt.defaults.state = $.extend({}, $.prompt.defaults.state, o);
};

/**
* position - Repositions the prompt (Used internally)
* @return void
*/
$.prompt.position = function(e){
    var restoreFx = $.fx.off,
        $state = $.prompt.getCurrentState(),
        stateObj = $.prompt.options.states[$state.data('jqi-name')],
        pos = stateObj? stateObj.position : undefined,
        $window = $(window),
        bodyHeight = document.body.scrollHeight, //$(document.body).outerHeight(true),
        windowHeight = $(window).height(),
        documentHeight = $(document).height(),
        height = bodyHeight > windowHeight ? bodyHeight : windowHeight,
        top = parseInt($window.scrollTop(),10) + ($.prompt.options.top.toString().indexOf('%') >= 0? 
                (windowHeight*(parseInt($.prompt.options.top,10)/100)) : parseInt($.prompt.options.top,10));

    // when resizing the window turn off animation
    if(e !== undefined && e.data.animate === false){
        $.fx.off = true;
    }

    $.prompt.jqib.css({
        position: "absolute",
        height: height,
        width: "100%",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0
    });
    $.prompt.jqif.css({
        position: "fixed",
        height: height,
        width: "100%",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0
    });

    // tour positioning
    if(pos && pos.container){
        var offset = $(pos.container).offset();

        if($.isPlainObject(offset) && offset.top !== undefined){
            $.prompt.jqi.css({
                position: "absolute"
            });
            $.prompt.jqi.animate({
                top: offset.top + pos.y,
                left: offset.left + pos.x,
                marginLeft: 0,
                width: (pos.width !== undefined)? pos.width : null
            });
            top = (offset.top + pos.y) - ($.prompt.options.top.toString().indexOf('%') >= 0? (windowHeight*(parseInt($.prompt.options.top,10)/100)) : parseInt($.prompt.options.top,10));
            $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: top }, 'slow', 'swing', function(){});
        }
    }
    // custom state width animation
    else if(pos && pos.width){
        $.prompt.jqi.css({
                position: "absolute",
                left: '50%'
            });
        $.prompt.jqi.animate({
                top: pos.y || top,
                left: pos.x || '50%',
                marginLeft: ((pos.width/2)*-1),
                width: pos.width
            });
    }
    // standard prompt positioning
    else{
        $.prompt.jqi.css({
            position: "absolute",
            top: top,
            left: '50%',//$window.width()/2,
            marginLeft: (($.prompt.jqi.outerWidth(false)/2)*-1)
        });
    }

    // restore fx settings
    if(e !== undefined && e.data.animate === false){
        $.fx.off = restoreFx;
    }
};

/**
* style - Restyles the prompt (Used internally)
* @return void
*/
$.prompt.style = function(){
    $.prompt.jqif.css({
        zIndex: $.prompt.options.zIndex,
        display: "none",
        opacity: $.prompt.options.opacity
    });
    $.prompt.jqi.css({
        zIndex: $.prompt.options.zIndex+1,
        display: "none"
    });
    $.prompt.jqib.css({
        zIndex: $.prompt.options.zIndex
    });
};

/**
* get - Get the prompt
* @return jQuery - the prompt
*/
$.prompt.get = function(state) {
    return $('.'+ $.prompt.currentPrefix);
};

/**
* addState - Injects a state into the prompt
* @param statename String - Name of the state
* @param stateobj Object - options for the state
* @param afterState String - selector of the state to insert after
* @return jQuery - the newly created state
*/
$.prompt.addState = function(statename, stateobj, afterState) {
    var state = "",
        $state = null,
        arrow = "",
        title = "",
        opts = $.prompt.options,
        $jqistates = $('.'+ $.prompt.currentPrefix +'states'),
        defbtn,k,v,i=0;

    stateobj = $.extend({},$.prompt.defaults.state, {name:statename}, stateobj);

    if(stateobj.position.arrow !== null){
        arrow = '<div class="'+ opts.prefix + 'arrow '+ opts.prefix + 'arrow'+ stateobj.position.arrow +'"></div>';
    }
    if(stateobj.title && stateobj.title !== ''){
        title = '<div class="lead '+ opts.prefix + 'title '+ opts.classes.title +'">'+  stateobj.title +'</div>';
    }
    state += '<div id="'+ opts.prefix +'state_'+ statename +'" class="'+ opts.prefix + 'state" data-jqi-name="'+ statename +'" style="display:none;">'+ 
                arrow + title +
                '<div class="'+ opts.prefix +'message '+ opts.classes.message +'">' + stateobj.html +'</div>'+
                '<div class="'+ opts.prefix +'buttons '+ opts.classes.buttons +'"'+ ($.isEmptyObject(stateobj.buttons)? 'style="display:none;"':'') +'>';

    for(k in stateobj.buttons){
        v = stateobj.buttons[k],
        defbtn = stateobj.focus === i || (isNaN(stateobj.focus) && stateobj.defaultButton === i) ? ($.prompt.currentPrefix + 'defaultbutton ' + opts.classes.defaultButton) : '';

        if(typeof v === 'object'){
            state += '<button class="'+ opts.classes.button +' '+ $.prompt.currentPrefix + 'button '+ defbtn;

            if(typeof v.classes !== "undefined"){
                state += ' '+ ($.isArray(v.classes)? v.classes.join(' ') : v.classes) + ' ';
            }

            state += '" name="' + opts.prefix + '_' + statename + '_button' + v.title.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi,'') + '" id="' + opts.prefix + '_' + statename + '_button' + v.title.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi,'') + '" value="' + v.value + '">' + v.title + '</button>';

        } else {
            state += '<button class="'+ $.prompt.currentPrefix + 'button '+ opts.classes.button +' '+ defbtn +'" name="' + opts.prefix + '_' + statename + '_button' + k.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi,'') + '" id="' + opts.prefix +  '_' + statename + '_button' + k.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi,'') + '" value="' + v + '">' + k + '</button>';

        }
        i++;
    }
    state += '</div></div>';

    $state = $(state);

    $state.on('impromptu:submit', stateobj.submit);

    if(afterState !== undefined){
        $jqistates.find('#'+ $.prompt.currentPrefix +'state_'+ afterState).after($state);
    }
    else{
        $jqistates.append($state);
    }

    $.prompt.options.states[statename] = stateobj;

    return $state;
};

/**
* removeState - Removes a state from the prompt
* @param state String - Name of the state
* @param newState String - Name of the state to transition to
* @return Boolean - returns true on success, false on failure
*/
$.prompt.removeState = function(state, newState) {
    var $state = $.prompt.getState(state),
        rm = function(){ $state.remove(); };

    if($state.length === 0){
        return false;
    }

    // transition away from it before deleting
    if($state.css('display') !== 'none'){
        if(newState !== undefined && $.prompt.getState(newState).length > 0){
            $.prompt.goToState(newState, false, rm);
        }
        else if($state.next().length > 0){
            $.prompt.nextState(rm);
        }
        else if($state.prev().length > 0){
            $.prompt.prevState(rm);
        }
        else{
            $.prompt.close();
        }
    }
    else{
        $state.slideUp('slow', rm);
    }

    return true;
};

/**
* getState - Get the state by its name
* @param state String - Name of the state
* @return jQuery - the state
*/
$.prompt.getState = function(state) {
    return $('#'+ $.prompt.currentPrefix +'state_'+ state);
};
$.prompt.getStateContent = function(state) {
    return $.prompt.getState(state);
};

/**
* getCurrentState - Get the current visible state
* @return jQuery - the current visible state
*/
$.prompt.getCurrentState = function() {
    return $.prompt.getState($.prompt.getCurrentStateName());
};

/**
* getCurrentStateName - Get the name of the current visible state
* @return String - the current visible state's name
*/
$.prompt.getCurrentStateName = function() {
    return $.prompt.currentStateName;
};

/**
* goToState - Goto the specified state
* @param state String - name of the state to transition to
* @param subState Boolean - true to be a sub state within the currently open state
* @param callback Function - called when the transition is complete
* @return jQuery - the newly active state
*/  
$.prompt.goToState = function(state, subState, callback) {
    var $jqi = $.prompt.get(),
        jqiopts = $.prompt.options,
        $state = $.prompt.getState(state),
        stateobj = jqiopts.states[$state.data('jqi-name')],
        promptstatechanginge = new $.Event('impromptu:statechanging');

    // subState can be ommitted
    if(typeof subState === 'function'){
        callback = subState;
        subState = false;
    }

    $.prompt.jqib.trigger(promptstatechanginge, [$.prompt.getCurrentStateName(), state]);

    if(!promptstatechanginge.isDefaultPrevented() && $state.length > 0){
        $.prompt.jqi.find('.'+ $.prompt.currentPrefix +'parentstate').removeClass($.prompt.currentPrefix +'parentstate');

        if(subState){ // hide any open substates
            // get rid of any substates
            $.prompt.jqi.find('.'+ $.prompt.currentPrefix +'substate').not($state)
                .slideUp(jqiopts.promptspeed)
                .removeClass('.'+ $.prompt.currentPrefix +'substate')
                .find('.'+ $.prompt.currentPrefix +'arrow').hide();

            // add parent state class so it can be visible, but blocked
            $.prompt.jqi.find('.'+ $.prompt.currentPrefix +'state:visible').addClass($.prompt.currentPrefix +'parentstate');

            // add substate class so we know it will be smaller
            $state.addClass($.prompt.currentPrefix +'substate');
        }
        else{ // hide any open states
            $.prompt.jqi.find('.'+ $.prompt.currentPrefix +'state').not($state)
                .slideUp(jqiopts.promptspeed)
                .find('.'+ $.prompt.currentPrefix +'arrow').hide();
        }
        $.prompt.currentStateName = stateobj.name;

        $state.slideDown(jqiopts.promptspeed,function(){
            var $t = $(this);

            // if focus is a selector, find it, else its button index
            if(typeof(stateobj.focus) === 'string'){
                $t.find(stateobj.focus).eq(0).focus();
            }
            else{
                $t.find('.'+ $.prompt.currentPrefix +'defaultbutton').focus();
            }

            $t.find('.'+ $.prompt.currentPrefix +'arrow').show(jqiopts.promptspeed);

            if (typeof callback === 'function'){
                $.prompt.jqib.on('impromptu:statechanged', callback);
            }
            $.prompt.jqib.trigger('impromptu:statechanged', [state]);
            if (typeof callback === 'function'){
                $.prompt.jqib.off('impromptu:statechanged', callback);
            }
        });
        if(!subState){
            $.prompt.position();
        }
    }
    return $state;
};

/**
* nextState - Transition to the next state
* @param callback Function - called when the transition is complete
* @return jQuery - the newly active state
*/  
$.prompt.nextState = function(callback) {
    var $next = $('#'+ $.prompt.currentPrefix +'state_'+ $.prompt.getCurrentStateName()).next();
    if($next.length > 0){
        $.prompt.goToState( $next.attr('id').replace($.prompt.currentPrefix +'state_',''), callback );
    }
    return $next;
};

/**
* prevState - Transition to the previous state
* @param callback Function - called when the transition is complete
* @return jQuery - the newly active state
*/  
$.prompt.prevState = function(callback) {
    var $prev = $('#'+ $.prompt.currentPrefix +'state_'+ $.prompt.getCurrentStateName()).prev();
    if($prev.length > 0){
        $.prompt.goToState( $prev.attr('id').replace($.prompt.currentPrefix +'state_',''), callback );
    }
    return $prev;
};

/**
* close - Closes the prompt
* @param callback Function - called when the transition is complete
* @param clicked String - value of the button clicked (only used internally)
* @param msg jQuery - The state message body (only used internally)
* @param forvals Object - key/value pairs of all form field names and values (only used internally)
* @return jQuery - the newly active state
*/  
$.prompt.close = function(callCallback, clicked, msg, formvals){
    if($.prompt.timeout){
        clearTimeout($.prompt.timeout);
        $.prompt.timeout = false;
    }

    if($.prompt.jqib){
        $.prompt.jqib.fadeOut('fast',function(){

            $.prompt.jqib.trigger('impromptu:close', [clicked,msg,formvals]);

            $.prompt.jqib.remove();

            $(window).off('resize',$.prompt.position);
        });
    }
    $.prompt.currentStateName = "";
};

/**
* Enable using $('.selector').prompt({});
* This will grab the html within the prompt as the prompt message
*/
$.fn.prompt = function(options){
    if(options === undefined){
        options = {};
    }
    if(options.withDataAndEvents === undefined){
        options.withDataAndEvents = false;
    }

    $.prompt($(this).clone(options.withDataAndEvents).html(),options);
};

})(jQuery);
```

Now, if I call the `$.prompt` function from `$(document.ready)`, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.prompt('Hello World!');
});
```

Or if I run it outside of any function, like this

```
$.prompt('Hello World!');
```

It works and shows a prompt with "Hello World" in it on page load, but if I call it from an onclick function, like this:

```
function onBtnCick() {
    $.prompt('Hello World!');
}
```

and on the html side, I have:

```
<a href='...' onclick='onBtnClick();'>...</a>
```

It doesn't do anything when I click on that link
I know the onBtnClick function is getting run though, because if I click the link, with:

```
function onBtnCick() {
    alert('testing');
}
```

It, shows a popup with 'testing' shown in it.
It's just the $.prompt function that can't get called from the onBtnClick function.

I've been trying to look up an answer for this question, and I think it has something to do with not being able to access jquery closures directly, but I'm still unclear on what to do.

How could I get this $.prompt function to work when clicking on the link?

As per request, I have added a JSFiddle to demonstrate the problem. You will notice the...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.prompt('Page Loaded');
});
```

works, but not

```
function onBtnClick() {
    $.prompt('Button Clicked');
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mnASg/1/

Comment: Please create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) on a service such as [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so that we can see how your program is structured.

Comment: did you try or view console log in firebug ?

Comment: I tried it on JSfiddle, it works fine, http://jsfiddle.net/jynQ7/

Comment: Actually, your JSfiddle only works, because you put all the javascript in the html part, try in in the javascript part, and it doesn't work. I need this to work with the javascript separate. I'm going to post my own JSFiddle to show you.

Comment: @Chihung Yu, I've added my JSFiddle. And you will notice it doesn't work. As I commented above, it only worked for you, because they put the javascript together with the html, but I need the javascript to work in a separate .js page.

Comment: @SSCCE, I have added a JSFiddle.    Chihung Yu made their own JSFiddle, and it worked for them, but only because they put all the javascript code in the HTML section, but I need it to work on a separate .js page.  Look at my question again, I have added the link to my jsFiddle at the bottom of my question.

Comment: @jmercier, Yes, I did view it in the console log in firebug, and it showed nothing, as if there was no error or anything, just nothing. (And I clicked on the javascript button in firebug too)

Comment: @user1296259 Try this one http://jsfiddle.net/mnASg/4/

Answer (score 1):

In your Jsfiddle

Add the click event in the document ready and remove the onclick in the html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.prompt('Page Loaded');

    $('a').click(function(){
      $.prompt('Button Clicked');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mnASg/7/

OR simply add window before the onBtnClick

```
window.onBtnClick = function() {
    $.prompt('Button Clicked');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mnASg/4/

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with the buttons not working in Firefox.  The issue was "use strict" at the top of the plug-in.  It caused the click event to not fire correctly.  This was only a problem in Firefox.  Chrome and IE worked correctly using "use strict."